# How SHOULD a variogram plot look like?

Tags: correlation, variogram

Say you fit a model **m**. You then calculate the variogram. In R, this can e.g. be done by using plot.Variogram using the nlme package on an lme object.

Say the plot indicates that yes, there is some correlation that disappears as the distance increases.

Then you model different correlation structures: Exponential, Gaussian, Spherical, all with or without nugget, and so on and so forth.

Here's my question: when you then plot the Variogram of these models .... **what should you see** in order to conclude that the model was a good fit?

1. Should you see a flat line of points indicating that the model took care of the correlation?
2. Should you see a curved line of points that fits the theoretically estimated line well?

For example, assume data is in actuality exponentially correlated. So I fit an exponential correlation structure. Should I see a flat line or points in the variogram, or should I see a curved line of points that fit the exponential curve using the estimated range parameter?

Answer (score 2):

> How SHOULD a variogram plot look like?

You seem to be aware of the various nomenclatures around a variogram. A high nugget (close to the sill) indicates that individual level error is large relative to the autoregressive correlation in consecutive observations. No nugget indicates the converse. The slope of the variogram can be described with various activation functions, exponential for fast growth (fewer lagged effects), quadratic or absolute value for slow growth (possible covariate history, complex dynamics, or distributed lags involved).

> Here's my question: when you then plot the Variogram of these models .... what should you see in order to conclude that the model was a good fit?

This is begging the question. A model can be perceived to have "good fit" if there is no residual error at all, and perfectly predicts all outcomes, in which case there is a 0 response variogram at all distances or times.

Comment: +1, but this would benefit from a couple of illustrative figures.